# Access Not Configured error while posting a message to google plus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-plus, google-api-client

I am using google-api-client gem to post message to google plus when a user logs in my application with his google plus credentials.

Below is my code.

```
 require 'google/api_client'
 require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
 require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
 keypath = Rails.root.join('config','poo-02a507f45ab4.p12').to_s
 key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(keypath, 'notasecret')


 client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'my app',
  :application_version => '1.0.0'
  )
urlshortener = client.discovered_api('urlshortener', 'v1')
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
:token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write'],
 :issuer => 'id@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
 :signing_key => key)
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

 batch = Google::APIClient::BatchRequest.new do |result|
   puts result.data
end
batch.add(:api_method => urlshortener.url.insert,:body_object => { 'longUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.co.in' })
client.execute(batch)
```

While trying this code its giving below error.

```
{\n \"domain\": \"usageLimits\",\n \"reason\": \"accessNotConfigured\",\n \"message\": \"Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.\",\n
```

I have enabled google + API and contacts API in developers console.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What type of credentials did you create?  key makes me think you created service account credentials.

Comment: Yes. I created and gave service account details.

Comment: Service account only gives you access it its account if you want to post from a user it has to be Oauth2.

Comment: Please explain in detail. How to use Oauth2?

Comment: Did you enable the URL Shortener API?

Comment: @abraham Yes i did.  But it's not posting my long_url to google plus. why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions such as those between a web application and a Google service. This scenario is called a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved.

If you want to post on behalf of a user you will need to be using Oauth2, then you will be able to authenticate the user.

**Update:**

So that you are aware it is not possible to post to a users Google+ time line. the best you can do is post something called [moments](http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) which isn't really the same thing.   An issue request was made for this in 2011 I think they have yet to add this feature.

Comment: that is a different question I think.  Not related to your current "Access Not Configured error" question

Comment: IS it possible to post message on google plus by using Oauth2?

Comment: To the normal time line no.  You cant post to google+ using the google+ api. you can post momemts though.  https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert  which isn't really the same thing.

Comment: but the error you are getting you would get no matter what you did because a service account doesn't have a google+ account to log into I don't think.

Comment: Is it not possible to post on a user wall/timeline?

Comment: No Google wont let us do that.  Issue request has been made like 2 years ago.

Comment: maybe I should have just posted "You cant do that" :)

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between post and moments?

Comment: Moments are associated with your app, or client id I think.  They wont show up on the main google+ page but you could list them and then display them inside your app.   Ask this as a different question and I will ping someone I know who could answer it better.